# ESP8266 breakout board use in KiCad

Tags: esp8266, kicad

I need to design a board with ESP8266 mounted onto a breakout board.

Here is the ESP8266 module: https://www.waveshare.com/esp-12f.htm

It is mounted onto this breakout board:

[image]

So what I need to design is a board with this breakout board.

But I wish to keep the original ESP-12F symbol. I couldn't find any matching footprint for this breakout board.

Is there any option to use **2x generic 8pinheader** when assigning a footprint for this symbol?

Comment: Make a foot print composed of two 8 pin headers spaced the appropriate distance apart.

Comment: You could do that but it is potentially error-prone. If you get the proper dimension and make a footprint correctly with the correct pin names it will be consistent and correct every time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to get the datasheet of the ESP module. At the end after electric specs and before packaging there should be footprint layouts with their dimensions. In KiCad you can make your own footprints with the footprint editor. You just need to create a footprint. Add SMD pads according to the dimensions on the datasheet and number and label the pads correctly.

The other option is to get the footprint on Ultra Librarian, a PCB footprint library website that is free, you only need to sign up. This footprint has the 6 bottom pads as well. If you like to not have them, make a copy of the footprint and edit it in KiCads footprint editor.

Edit: I realized you wanted a breakout footprint that works with the ESP Symbol. That is possible. That will require you to create a footprint, add 2 8 pin headers. Change the pin numbers to be correct, then you can assign this footprint and it will automatically connect the pins to the correct nets.